# How to refactor early returns in a function?

Tags: javascript

The issue here is that I've got multiple early return points where code is essentially duplicated.

I would like to learn a way to <s>optimise</s> refactor this and either:

1. `return` only once - or
2. do not repeat the `return undefined;` part

   ```
   function fn(foo) {
     if (!foo) {
       return undefined;
     }

     const bar = some_calculations(foo)
     if (!bar) {
       return undefined;
     }

     const baz = some_calculations_with(bar, foo)
     if (!baz) {
       return undefined;
     }

     return baz * 2
   }
   ```

Comment: If theres no reason to continue the function then I'd argue it's more efficient to return early. IMHO There's nothing particularly suboptimal about what you've written, since all tests appear to be different

Comment: What do you mean "optimize"? This doesn't appear to have anything to do with optimization. Do you mean improve the code style?

Comment: In general, you can avoid multiple returns by using `let`, conditionally assigning it, then returning that at the end of your function.

Comment: A function should have a single responsibility, yours has three. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Comment: By optimize - I meant refactor

Comment: @chrispbacon, not really. What if it triggers causing side-effects and then operates on their results?

Comment: @jmargolisvt, yes, it works sometimes. But in this particulare function with your proposal - `some_calculations` will have to additionally account for passed-in `foo` being `undefined`. Which will simply duplicate and propagate the `if (!foo) {
    return undefined;
  }` inside of `some_calculations`. Which is bad, you agree?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code is optimized just fine as far as performance goes. Additionally, I think it's very easy to read and understand. The one concern (as pointed out in the comments) is simply that it's performing too many duties.

That in mind, given your parameters...

> - `return` only once
> - do not repeat the `return undefined;` part

...you could short-circuit the assignments in an `if`. Having no `return` at all is the same as `return undefined`.

```js
const some_calculations = (foo) => "bar";
const some_calculations_with= (bar, foo) => "baz";

function fn(foo) {
  if (foo && (bar = some_calculations(foo)) && (baz = some_calculations_with(bar, foo)))
    return baz;
}

let noResult = fn();
console.log(noResult);
 
let result = fn("foo");
console.log(result);
```

But my two cents? Leave it as it is, or break down the function.

Comment: The `fn` code is quite unreadable now which is not what I wanted to achieve

Comment: At no point in your question did you mention readability. You requested a refactor with *"`return` only once"* and *"do not repeat the `return undefined;` part"*, both of which I believe my answer has satisfied. If you want a readable version, I would suggest you stick with what you've got. In the future, if you want an answer that provides XYZ, make sure that your question *asks* for XYZ.

Comment: I don't think I have to be explicit about obvious things. I upvoted your answer, but cannot accept it.